# Cocoa-AppleScript - Change xib label with applescript in xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, applescript, xib

I am writing a Cocoa-AppleScript app and I am trying to replace the text in a xib label after my tasks complete. Here is the code that I have:

```
set the contents of successLabel to "SUCCESS!"
```

successLabel is a label that is setup in the xib, and it is hooked up to the App Delegate outlet. It also has the Identifier set to successLabel.

I feel like I am not accessing the label correctly. How do you find the xib label in applescript? Thanks!

Comment: Get yourself a copy of Shane Stanley's [AppleScriptObjC Explored](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/book.html) - it's the definitive guide to Cocoa-AppleScript development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For whatever reason, the link in the xib was not working, even thought it was showing to be hooked up. I deleted the link to the app delegate, right clicked on the app delegate cube, and selected my label again and it worked. I don't know why it was not working, although I have seen links get broken in the same way writing iOS. I am using Xcode 5.